# How to get remote installed VSCode extensions into local workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

To put it short: there is a button in VSCode to get extensions, that are installed locally, to also be installed remotely:

[image]

Now I am looking for the reverse: how can I get remotely installed extensions also installed locally? Is there a better way than uninstalling them one-by-one from the remote and reinstalling them locally?